# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTracks' of null

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I've been trying to change webRTC broadcast source to many-to-one

I'm thinking that one-to-many(broadcast) and many-to-one is little different[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAzbt.png

they had peerConnections and it was all good.

caller sent MediaStream to all callee.

so i thought

Let's get signalling from caller to callee, and bring MediaStream from Callee to Caller.

so i put this code to the callee side

callee.js

```js
socket.on('offer', (id, description) => {
  peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(config);
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then((stream) => {
      video.srcObject = stream;
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));

  let stream = video.srcObject;
  stream
    .getTracks()
    .forEach((track) => peerConnection.addTrack(track, stream));

  peerConnection
    .setRemoteDescription(description)
    .then(() => peerConnection.createAnswer())
    .then((sdp) => peerConnection.setLocalDescription(sdp))
    .then(() => {
      socket.emit('answer', id, peerConnection.localDescription);
    });

  peerConnection.onicecandidate = (event) => {
    if (event.candidate) {
      socket.emit('candidate', id, event.candidate);
    }
  };
});
```

caller.js

```js
socket.on('answer', (id, description) => {
  peerConnections[id].setRemoteDescription(description);
  peerConnections.ontrack = (event) => {
    video.srcObject = event.streams[0];
  };
});
```

and i got "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTracks' of null" this error from callee.js

Could you give me any idea for this?

THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

Since the stream is acquired by Promise, getTracks() will be executed before getUserMedia().
So, modify it so that it executes after the promise.

exp: no tested

```js
socket.on("offer", (id, description) => {
    peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(config);
    peerConnection.onicecandidate = event => {
        if (event.candidate) {
            socket.emit("candidate", id, event.candidate);
        }
    };
    navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia(constraints)
        .then(stream => {
            video.srcObject = stream;
            stream.getTracks().forEach(track => peerConnection.addTrack(track, stream));
        })
        .then(peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(description))
        .then(() => peerConnection.createAnswer())
        .then(sdp => peerConnection.setLocalDescription(sdp))
        .then(() => {
            socket.emit("answer", id, peerConnection.localDescription);
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
});
```